# How to upload zip data with alamofire?

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I try to upload data using Alamofire

Issue is: if I try to upload image from project it works ok, but if I try to upload zip dir I got error and timeout exception

There is my code which produces timeout exception

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
    alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath)
alamoFireManager.upload(fileData,
                        to: url,
                        method: .post,
                        headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON {}
```

And here is code which works fine

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
    alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyImage", withExtension: "jpg")

alamoFireManager.upload(fileURL,
                            to: url,
                            method: .post,
                            headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON {}
```

I tried to pass Data() to `upload request` also I tried pass reference to zip dit `URL` to upload request, also I tried `InputStream(url: fileURL!)!` but without success...

What am I doing wrong? how to send zip data to the server?

if there is some question feel free to ask!

Comment: why not the filepath of the zip file with extension `zip`?

Comment: you use the same url? did your endpoint can handle zip files?

Comment: maybe also your timeout with 10seconds is very short

Comment: add this to see how much is uploaded: ` .uploadProgress { progress in
        // Called on main dispatch queue by default
        print("Upload progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    }`

Comment: what you exactly mean with `zip dir`? its a zip file

Comment: try this example with your zip file https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-a-file

Comment: @muescha thanks ! I have already solve... It was because of server side, but quite strange why I was getting timeout exception instead of some error... anyway now it is ok

Comment: @muescha maybe you know how to help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982122/how-to-execute-alamofire-background-upload-request

Comment: please update your question or delete or add an answer with your solution - this helps others to waste no time with your not as solved marked question.

Comment: @muescha if you would like, you can add answer I will accept it. Because you give me idea to check server side. If not I will add answer for myself

Comment: pls you do, because you find the answer. and yes it is possible you can answer your own question and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found the issue, server side does not accept my request. Also, there is some confusion, because if I try to download an image file from my project it works, but if the file is selected from the document directory then there is an issue.

Anyway if someone has a similar issue try to check your server side.

Try to check if your request came to server and with content inside.