# Alamofire Background Upload doesn't print Progress while app is in Background

Tags: swift, file-upload, background, alamofire

I am uploading `PDF` file to server using `Alamofire`. I have created `backgroundSessionManager` to make sure that app uploads file while app is in background. The code works perfectly as I am getting call over `backgroundCompletionHandler` from `AppDelegate` method `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`.

The progress is I am showing progress and when app goes in background the progress is stuck and `.uploadProgress` completion is also not calling. Due to this when user goes in background and after some time when comes back then progress is not increasing.

**Shared Instance:**

```
class Networking {
    static let sharedInstance = Networking()
    public var backgroundSessionManager: Alamofire.SessionManager // your web services you intend to keep running when the system backgrounds your app will use this
    private init() {
        self.backgroundSessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.dw.myapp"))

        var backgroundCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)? {
            get {
                return backgroundSessionManager.backgroundCompletionHandler
            }
            set {
                backgroundSessionManager.backgroundCompletionHandler = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Uploading file code**

```
Networking.sharedInstance.backgroundSessionManager.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartData) in
 }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: "\(url)", method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                //Does not call while app is in background
                        Helper.dispatchMain {
                            print(progress)
                            print("Upload Time ", Date())
                        }
                    })
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        print("Response Time ", Date())
                        print("Response Time ", Date())
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion!(["message" : error],false)
                }
            }
```

I have search over SO and github page but din't find the solution. Any one can pls guide if I am making any mistake?

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/41986000/4601900

Comment: Yes! For me, background code works fine, the prbm is stated as `.uploadProgress` stops calling.

Comment: Actually I have found answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55024775/3402095

Comment: I think you need to reattach closure to particular upload task

Comment: @Whirlwind Is that working? I need to check

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Yeah it works and Alalmofire's upload progress is called. You have to use background task, to let the iOS know, you have to finish smth in background.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Did you enable background services in xcode capabilities]

Hope this will work, let me know if you are still facing it

Comment: Nope, the solution you have provided is must for background downloading so I have already enabled it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try with enabling the **External accessory communication** capability inside your app's Background mode Capabilities.