# Alamofire progress callback stops working after returning from background

Tags: ios, swift, background, alamofire, multipartform-data

I have a method that uploads (video) data to the server, and it looks like this:

```
 static func upload(video data:Data, named name:String, parameters:[String:Any],  toUrl url:URL, progress:@escaping (Double)->Void, completion:@escaping(Bool)->Void){
manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background("com.app.backgroundtransfer")
        manager.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "filedata", fileName: name, mimeType: "video/quicktime")

            for key in parameters.keys{

                if let val = parameters[key] as? String{

                    multipartFormData.append(val.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: key)
                }
            }

        }, to: url) {
            (encodingResult) in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (uploadProgress) in

                    progress(uploadProgress.fractionCompleted)
                    //this one stops getting called

                })
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                   // but this one gets called at the end.
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
              print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    }
```

So the problem is, I can't update UI properly when returned from background (while in the middle of upload).

Why this progress callback stops working (after returning from background) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alamofire isn't really compatible with background sessions. Since it's a closure-based API that can't be persisted when the app goes into the background, your progress closures aren't being reconnected when the app is foregrounded. We recommend you use `URLSession` directly or use the background task API instead of background sessions.

Comment: Hi Jon... Is this still a thing in Alamofire 5?

Comment: Yes, nothing's changed in that regard. Like @Whirlwind posted, using the background task API is an alternative to background sessions.

Answer (score 2):

So what I have done, is used background task (also did it without Alamofire completely) and it worked. Like this:

```
 var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = .invalid

    func registerBackgroundTask() {
        backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask {
            self.endBackgroundTask()
        }
        assert(backgroundTask != .invalid)
    }

    func endBackgroundTask() {
        print("Background task ended.")
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
        backgroundTask = .invalid
    }

 APIClient.manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.app.backgroundtransfer"))
            self.registerBackgroundTask()

            APIClient.upload(video: video, named: videoDetailsModel.videoURL!.lastPathComponent, parameters: self.uploadParameters, toUrl: url, progress: {[weak self] (percentage) in
                guard let `self` = self else {return}

                print("Progress \(percentage)")
                self.progressBar.progress = CGFloat(percentage)
                }, completion: { [weak self] (success) in
                    guard let `self` = self else {return}
                    if(success){
                        print("Video successfully uploaded")
                        self.endBackgroundTask()
                        self.progressBar.progress = 1.0
                    }else{
                        print("Video upload was not successfull")
                    }
            })
```

Now progress callbacks work normally and you can still use Alamofire to pack the multipartformdata as I was using it, or for whatever reason you are using it.