# Whether alamofire supports Background Uploading or not?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have to upload multiple large no of videos/images/files using background upload and not getting any solution till now.

Comment: It seems so. E.g., this answer shows how to configure Alamofire with a background URL session configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64605997/7016052 This also might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982122/how-to-execute-alamofire-background-upload-request

Comment: First of all thanks for responding @lazarevzubov .does this work with alamofire 5?

Comment: I don't know unfortunately. That's why I'm just commenting my suggestion and not posting an answer. But it seems at least worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

No, Alamofire 5 does not support background `URLSessionConfiguration`s.