# Upload zip file using Alamofire

Tags: php, swift, file-upload, zip, alamofire

How can I upload a file that I have in my Documents/Inbox directory using Alamofire?

There are many topics on this but they all cover uploading photos, which is not what I want. I would like to upload a zip file to my that uses PHP

Below is what I use to get the file's content, but I'm not sure if this is correct:

```
do {
     let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: "\(NSHomeDirectory())/Documents/Inbox/file.zip")
    let Contents = directoryContents
    print("File is okay")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Edit: I tried the Alamofire examples without success: *(Please note that I am uploading a file that a user has submitted through the app via "Import to" rather than a file that is inside the xcode project.)*

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977486/how-to-upload-zip-data-with-alamofire ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload zip data with alamofire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977486/how-to-upload-zip-data-with-alamofire)

Comment: Did you review the example on the Alamofire GitHub page?  https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-a-file

Comment: @nathan @ninjaproger It's not a duplicate. I have already looked at this and that code throws syntax errors and use `Bundle.main.url` which does not work for me.

Comment: @JAL Yes, but unfortunately those do not help either. Those are for uploading files in the bundle

Comment: Right now it's a bit unclear if the question is how to get the file or send it using Alamofire. What have you tested and what were the results ? You need to prove more details. What do you mean by "Import to" ?